# Juju bootstrap fails for Windows Azure

Tags: juju, cloud

I am trying to play with Juju on Windows Azure. I did the configuration part, however the bootstrap fails on a network configuration error:

```
2013-10-29 10:08:49 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 PUT request failed: BadRequest - XML Schema validation error in network configuration at line 75,18. (http code 400: Bad Request)
```

How can I troubleshoot? Can I find somewhere the XML file to examine it?

Thanks!
Thomas.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem before.  To solve it I removed `.juju/environments/azure.jenv` and bootstrapped again and it worked.  Your mileage may vary, however.  Also, i had to add --upload-tools to the bootstrap command.

**edit**: that was then, but now I can't seem to replicate my earlier success, I am getting a different error, described at [juju bootstrap fails in Azure (BadRequest - The affinity group name is empty or was not specified.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/388419/juju-bootstrap-fails-in-azure-badrequest-the-affinity-group-name-is-empty-or).  So, I can't promise that this will solve your issue.