# juju bootstrap fails in Azure (BadRequest - The affinity group name is empty or was not specified.)

Tags: juju

Commmand and results copied below.  I'm aware of https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1236136 but this is a separate issue as I am using the West US region for everything.

This occurs when trying to bootstrap from an Azure VM and from a standalone machine.

Also, it seemed to come up in 1.16.3 too.

Certificates have been uploaded per instructions.  Also, this occurs if I open the --upload-tools argument.

```
dm@prd-juju:~/development/docmunch/ops/juju/juju-config$ rm -f ~/.juju/environments/* && juju bootstrap --show-log --upload-tools
2013-12-09 19:46:23 INFO juju.environs.tools build.go:162 found existing jujud
2013-12-09 19:46:23 INFO juju.environs.tools build.go:172 target: /tmp/juju-tools155984108/jujud
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:235 built 1.16.4.1-saucy-amd64 (4537kB)
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:66 listing available tools
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:90 found 2 tools
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:100 listing target bucket
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:113 found 0 tools in target; 2 tools to be copied
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:143 copying 1.16.4.1-precise-amd64 from file:///tmp/932795739/tools/releases/juju-1.16.4.1-precise-amd64.tgz
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:157 copying tools/releases/juju-1.16.4.1-precise-amd64.tgz
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:171 downloaded tools/releases/juju-1.16.4.1-precise-amd64.tgz (4537kB), uploading
2013-12-09 19:46:28 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:172 download 4537kB, uploading
2013-12-09 19:46:29 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:143 copying 1.16.4.1-saucy-amd64 from file:///tmp/932795739/tools/releases/juju-1.16.4.1-saucy-amd64.tgz
2013-12-09 19:46:29 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:157 copying tools/releases/juju-1.16.4.1-saucy-amd64.tgz
2013-12-09 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:171 downloaded tools/releases/juju-1.16.4.1-saucy-amd64.tgz (4537kB), uploading
2013-12-09 19:46:30 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:172 download 4537kB, uploading
2013-12-09 19:46:31 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:118 copied 2 tools
2013-12-09 19:46:31 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:120 generating tools metadata
2013-12-09 19:46:31 INFO juju.environs.tools simplestreams.go:277 Writing tools/streams/v1/index.json
2013-12-09 19:46:31 INFO juju.environs.tools simplestreams.go:277 Writing tools/streams/v1/com.ubuntu.juju:released:tools.json
2013-12-09 19:46:31 INFO juju.environs.sync sync.go:128 tools metadata written
2013-12-09 19:46:32 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:85 reading tools with major.minor version 1.16
2013-12-09 19:46:32 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:93 filtering tools by version: 1.16.4.1
2013-12-09 19:46:32 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:96 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-12-09 19:46:34 INFO juju.environs.boostrap bootstrap.go:50 bootstrapping environment "azure"
2013-12-09 19:46:34 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:85 reading tools with major.minor version 1.16
2013-12-09 19:46:34 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:93 filtering tools by version: 1.16.4.1
2013-12-09 19:46:34 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:96 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-12-09 19:46:48 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 POST request failed: BadRequest - The affinity group name is empty or was not specified. (http code 400: Bad Request)
```

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and vote to close this as we can handle this better in the bug report, thanks!